# Why is my program not outputting my array elements?

Tags: java, arrays

What I am trying to do is output each element of my array to the system. Below is how the array elements were entered and my issue is beneath that. Why is it not outputting the array elements?

```
for (int i = 0; i <arrayLength; i++) {
    double array[] = new double[arrayLength];
    array[i] = IO.readInt("Enter number: " + (i+1));
    count++;
} 
for (int i = 0; i <arrayLength; i++) {
    System.out.println(array[i]); 
}
```

Comment: You're creating a new array each time through the first loop.

Comment: A remark on your code: please do not write `double array[]`, rather use `double[] array`. While both a legal, the former is the C-style of defining an array. In Java, it is preferred to write the brackets next to the type, since they influence the type of the variable.

Comment: Hmmm. Should I post the rest of my code?

Comment: @Turing85 Thank you! I'll make some changes and check back later.

Answer (score 2):

It's because you create a new array every time in the first loop. You have to declare the array before the loop.

```
double array[] = new double[arrayLength];

for (int i = 0; i <arrayLength; i++)
{
    array[i] = IO.readInt("Enter number: " + (i+1));
} 
for (int i = 0; i <arrayLength; i++)
{
    System.out.println(array[i]); 
}
```

Comment: Yes he is right. This was the answer I was looking for so thank you for that.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a new array on each iteration so please keep the array declaration outside the loops.

```
double array[] = new double[arrayLength];
for (int i = 0; i <arrayLength; i++)
{
    array[i] = IO.readInt("Enter number: " + (i+1));
    System.out.println(array[i]); //reference the value saved in variable out of the for scope.
}
```